# Android SurfaceView, extender de View o Drawable?

Tags: android

¿Cómo sería más aconsejable enlazar una imagen de la carpeta drawable con una clase propia, para manejar programáticamente dentro de una Surface View, extendiendo de View o de Drawable? Lo que pretendo es que un bitmap siga una trayectoria marcada por el dedo, sobre una Surface View. Chao, saludos ...

Comment: Entonces únicamente quieres imprimir las coordenadas del recorrido de tu dedo?

Comment: Concretando mejor, la cuestión sería: sobre una surfaceview, voy a hacer que un bitmap contenido en la carpeta drawable, siga una trayectoria, y necesito gestionar esta imagen como objeto. ¿Para usar el bitmap como objeto, es mejor crear su clase herendando de View o de Drawable?